# Filter size in CNNs and how they relate to overfitting/underfitting

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, cnn

Would a smaller filter size (e.g. 3x3) potentially be more prone to overfitting than a larger filter size (e.g. 10x10) in a CNN.

I know it's all dependent on the specific dataset at hand, but I'm just trying to understand this in terms of the bias variance tradeoff.

In my interpretation, having a smaller filter size would train the CNN to identify more local patterns in each input image, potentially leading to greater variance (and the overfitting problem), while a larger filter size would lead to better identification of more global trends in each image, potentially leading to greater bias (subsequently underfitting).

Is this interpretation correct in theory?

Thanks

Comment: a plausible answer is that the more the trainable parameters of a model the less likely to overfit (training epochs and dataset kept similar). So larger CNN filters means more trainable parameters for the same training time and data, thus less likely to overfit (all others being same of course and overfit is relative to a model with less parameters)

Comment: Doesn't it lead to a greater chance of overfitting if you've got more trainable parameters?

Comment: Relative to another model with less parameters, given same data and training epochs the model with less parameters is more likely to overfit than the other. So it is relative all else being similar

Comment: To clarify my previous comments. What is meant is that the less the trainable parameters a model has, the less training time it needs to achieve its learning capacity (which means it -over-fitted as much as it is capable). Eg a model with 1 parameter needs roughly 1 epoch to learn it and achieve its learning capacity. On the other hand a model with many parameters needs way more training time to achieve its learning capacity. So in this sense given 2 models and same training epochs, the simpler model will learn ("-over-fit") **sooner** than the more complex model.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your theory is correct.

A smaller filter size will be catching local patterns and more local patterns will be accumulated as the filter size goes down.

On the other hand, a larger filter size is computationally costly and also, looks at the larger picture.

In practice, a stack of two 3×3 conv. layers (without spatial pooling in between) has an effective receptive field of 5×5; three such layers have a 7 × 7 effective receptive field. Also, using 3x3 layers is cheaper (18 parameters vs 25 parameters in case of 5x5 filter and 27 parameters vs 49 parameters in case of 7x7 filters). [Source](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.1556.pdf)

Comment: Great answer! And it makes sense because you could introduce more layers with a 3*3 compared to a 5*5, introducing greater non-linearity and helping the network learn effectively on more complex data.